# how do I customize dialog to the detail page of an answer set?

Tags: bixby

In a dialog file like

```
dialog (Result) {
  match: Content (this)

  template("Welcome!")
}
```

where Content is an an answer set and the user proceeds from browsing the answer set to each detail page, how do I customize so that the dialog is different for each mode -- list, summary, detail?

I am looking to do something along the lines of if mode = Detail then template = Content.text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this setting to your capsule.bxb file.

```
runtime-version (2) {
   overrides {
     allow-dialogs-on-detail-pages (true)
   }
 }
```

In your result-view, you can define your details dialog in the message section.  For example:

```
 message {
   // A single result?
   if (size(this) == 1) {
       template (Details Dialog!!!)
     }
  }
```

Comment: Ahahaha! I'm glad I asked because I would probably have NEVER thought to look there.