# How to locate default dialog for detail page?

Tags: bixby

I successfully display a dialog on detail page thanks to guidance from [how do I customize dialog to the detail page of an answer set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60133932/how-do-i-customize-dialog-to-the-detail-page-of-an-answer-set). But yet I am unable to customise the dialog shown on the detail page, "Here what i found"

[image]

Would love to know where could i find out the concept/dialog that is relate to the default dialog on detail page, based on the debug console? or there is others ways?

[Extra infomation] I display detail page with layout match,

```
}else-if (size(this.audioItem)==1){
                layout-match (this.audioItem){
                    mode (Details)
                }

            }
```

It success. But when i customise the result view's message,

```
message{
    if (size(this.audioItem)==1){
        template ("Can?")
    }
```

The message come out 'Here what i found'.

Answer (score 1):

The default dialog part might be a bit confusing, there is no need to do dialog model in your case. To replace the default "here is what I found", just use the `message` child-key in any view model.

For example, the following would display "In result view" instead of "here is what I found"

```
result-view {
  match: TextName (this) 
  message ("In result view")
  render {
    if (size(this)>1) {
```

To check the complete example, [download capsule from GitHub](https://github.com/MinChengVivLabs/example.inputWithName).

Comment: Question: does "message" in view trump a dialog model if it exists?  If you have both, which is provided to user?

Comment: @FredZimmerman I cannot say I am 100% sure, but I believe those are not in contradiction of each other. I would say in the above example, no matter what dialog model you defined for TextName, The message will be "In result view" if `message` child-key is provided. Or the message would be "Here is what I found" if no `message` child-key is provided. Different dialog model would only for the different moment. For example, the value dialog, only triggered by using `#{value(this)}`. Of course, you are welcome to try some samples and confirm.

Comment: Strange, the dialog on my detail page doesn't change with the added template, what  change is the dialog on the list page. Is that i match to a wrong concept?

Comment: You may first try `allow-dialogs-on-detail-pages (true)`, read more on https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/capsule.runtime-version.overrides.allow-dialogs-on-detail-pages

Comment: Sorry, i think you misunderstood my intention, i tried `allow-dialogs-on-detail-pages (true)` and the detail pages dialog show up with "Here is what i found". And i wish to customize it.

Comment: The message is customizable by using the result-view -> message child-key. I would suspect a logic issue in if-else statement. You can either post the complete result-view model file so I can update answer, or you can send us the capsule by submitting a support ticket using the "contact support" feature in IDE while capsule is open and synced.